# Cart rule works but one built similar doesn't

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have a grouped product. When it is added to the cart, three products get added and we offer a 20% discount for the "group". I created a rule and it has worked flawlessly for several years. I went to create another one exactly like it but with different SKUs and it doesn't work.

Definition:
[image]

Conditions:
[image]

Actions:
[image]

Why would the rule work for the Essentials Package but not for the Agency Value Package?

Comment: "Fixed amount discount for whole cart" vs. "Fixed amount discount" - could that be the issue?

Comment: I also see the `ANY` vs. `ALL` in the Actions. I'm testing now.

Comment: Post as answer, please. Not sure how to accept yours and @Amasty's answer as answer because both were the problem.

Comment: MB34, so the answer is set condition as ANY instead of ALL. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, that was the most likely cause but the discount for the whole cart makes it discount $20 of the 3 products, not $20 PER product. So it really was BOTH answers.

Comment: I can't select both as answer but yours is what actually made the rule begin to work. I will give @mpaepper answer an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second rule you apply discount for given products only (listed in the "Apply the rule only ...")

However there is an error.  The condition is **ALL**.

So a product should have SKU PUPGP...  AND PUBAA... and PUBST... at the same time.  It's impossible, because any product has only one SKU.

Try to set the condition as **ANY**.

Answer (score 1):

On the left side you have "Fixed amount discount for whole cart" while on the right side you have "Fixed amount discount"